# HP PROLIANT 1300w hstns-pa01 PSU orange/amber light

Tags: linux, hp, hp-proliant, power-supply-unit

I bought an HP Server PSU (For mining) - HP PROLIANT 1300w (hstns-pa01) -  I plugged it in and it was working perfectly for 12h and 20min, then the rig shut down ( because no power) but PSU fan was still running. I stopped the PSU and unplugged it from the wall. After few hours I tried again. When I plug the PSU in the wall the fan starts spinning, but I get no power and an orange/amber light.

[PSU label picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exFSL.jpg)

Comment: Hardware fails. Replace.

Answer (score 2):

The AA23531 is [used in](https://www.walmart.com/ip/HP-AA23531-1300-Watt-Redundant-Power-Supply-For-Proliant-Dl580-G3-G4-G5-Ml570-G3-Used/263513268) among other things, the Proliant DL580 G3 through G5. The [documentation for the DL 580 G3's LED indicators](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c00385409&docLocale=en_US) mentions two LEDs on the power supply. Only one of them is amber. If that LED is on, it indicates:

> No AC power to this power supply

And if it is flashing:

> Power supply failure (over current)

Meanwhile, the [G5 documentation](https://support.hpe.com/hpesc/public/docDisplay?docId=c00385409&docLocale=en_US#c00385409_PowerSupply_LEDs) is slightly different. On that one, the amber LED indicates:

> Power supply failure (includes overvoltage and overtemperature)

So, if you are sure you have power going into the power supply, your power supply has failed.

Depending on the specific model and generation of the server you are using the power supply in, you might be able to find slightly more detail in the documentation, but it is unlikely to lead to a different conclusion.